# scrollTop not working when it is in an iframe

Tags: jquery

Consider this page and the button down the page : http://test.debord.eu/scrollto/

When you click the button, you scroll to the top of the page; then wherever you click, you go back to the button.

Now I embed this page in an frame: http://test.debord.eu/scrollto/iframe.html

And the scrollTop method doesn't work anymore.
Can somebody tell me how to make this scrolltop working trough an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollTop` method works on the scroll bar of the current document.

In your [first example](http://test.debord.eu/scrollto/), the scroll bar is in this `document`. So on click `scrollTop` works.

Now in [2nd case](http://test.debord.eu/scrollto/iframe.html) scroll bar is present in main window not inside `<iframe src="http://test.debord.eu/scrollto/">` frame.

Try adding `height:1000px;` to `scrollto` iframe element.

now `click` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification